# Replacing lines in files with file contents

Tags: files, sed, awk, perl, replace

I have several files which contain some PHP `include`s and I want to substitute them with the file contents. The file looks like

```
foo
<?php
include("file1.php");
?>
bar
baz
<?php
include("file2.php");
include("file3.php");
?>
more content
```

So after `foo` should be the content of file1.php and after `baz` should be first content of file2.php followed by file3.php. 
I want also remove the `<?php` and `?>` tags in both cases. What is a good way to resolve this?

Assume the following file contents:

1. `file1.php`: is empty
2. `file2.php`: `<p>Hello`
3. `file3.php`: `World</p>`

So the resulting file should look like:

```
foo
bar
baz
<p>Hello
World</p>
more content
```

The word `foo`, `bar` etc. are just expletives within the real file there could be any text.

Comment: You want to remove <?php *to* ?> or what?

Comment: I restated my question a bit. I want to get the file contents plus remove the PHP tags.

Comment: have you checked my bash script ?

Comment: ohh, sorry , i haven't see your updated question, let me try again

Comment: i have updated my script , so please check and let me know

Comment: is your issue solve ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are PHP substitutions anyway, so just run it through php:

```
$ php file-main.php 
foo
bar
baz
<p>Hello
World</p>
more content


$ php file-main.php > file-main-new.php
```

Comment: what about include file contains `echo "hello";` it will displayed only hello, so it useful in new.php ?

Comment: It works for the OP's sample case, but yes - actual PHP code would be executed rather than copied

Answer (score 3):

awk wrapped:

```
awk '
    /</ || /\?>/ {next;} 
    /include/ {
        if (match($0,"\".*php")){
            f = substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1);
            while ( getline < f ){
                print;
            }
        } 
        next;
    } 
    {print;}
' YOURFILE
```

Can embed in shell, mend your one-liner, or save into an awk script which is recommended...

Comment: it's giving error : `awk: line 2: regular expression compile failed (missing operand)`

Comment: My Bad. I forgot to escape the "?" in regex, which is not needed in gawk but needed on proper AWK like mawk and others. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

```
k=1
while read line
do


        if [[ "${line}" == "<?php" ]] || [[ "${line}" == "?>" ]]; then
        :
        elif [[ "${line}" =~ "include" ]]; then
        ((k++))
        file=$line
                while read include_line
                do
                echo $include_line  | grep -Ev '<\?php|\?>' >> newfile.php
                done <${file:9:9}
       # cat file$k.php >> newfile.php
        else
        echo $line >> newfile.php
        fi

done </tmp/inputfile
```

Comment: I think, you somehow misunderstood me. I don't want to skip the `include`, but I want to insert the content of the file which is in the `include`-statement.

Comment: have you tried that ? it's just skipping <?php ?> before foo as you want.

Comment: Please run that script with test files and see the result.

Comment: It skips `<?php` and `?>`, but does not include any file contents.

Comment: now it will include that file as you want

Comment: Thanks, this solution nearly works. As you might have guessed the filenames `file1.php`, `file2.php` etc. are sample names. So `${file:9:9}` will not work in any case.  I used sed here: `$(echo $file | sed 's,.*include("\(["]\+\)").*,\1,')`.

Comment: That seems to be a script for `/bin/bash` (but not running on general `/bin/sh`, right? (using `=~` operator)) Could you add a shebang line or so if that's the case?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how structured your data is, you could do it like this with sed:

```
<infile.php sed -n 's:include("\([^"]\+\)");:/&/ { r \1\nd }:p' | 
  sed -f - -e '/<\?php\|\?>/d' infile.php
```

The first invocation of sed writes a sed script with lines like:

```
/include("file1.php");/ { r file1.php
d }
```

Which replace matched lines with the file content they mention. The last sed then executes this script along with `/<\?php\|\?>/d`, which deletes lines with `<?php` and `?>`.

Answer (score 0):

There would be better awk, sed, perl solutions to this. But I am giving a simple editing tip of `vim` that can be used here, which is used to insert the contents of a files into other.

1. Delete the `<?php` and `?>` tags.
2. Delete the `include` line, and insert the respective contents of the file using `:r file1.php`. This will insert the contents of the file `file1.php` at the next line from the cursor.
3. Repeat the steps for other such `include` statements.

#### example

```
$ cat file1.txt
This is a content in file1.
```

The screenshots show the changes

[image: before]

The contents of `file1.txt` are placed in the `mainFile.txt`
[image: after]

You can check more about `:r` in the vim help or [this reference link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_a_file).

Comment: This seems too much work if you have hundreds of files. However you can record a sequence of keystrokes and replay it, like: `/ *include("<RET>f"lgfvaG:b#<RET>kpjdd`. Now one has to remove the PHP tags and is done. :-)